# cannot find method for arguments

Tags: gradle

I have project with multiple subprojects

```
rootProject\
    projectA\
    projectB\
```

In my root `build.gradle` I declared a method:

```
def doSomeAction(Project proj) {
}
```

In my `subprojects` block I have a definition of the task:

```
task myTask {
    doLast {
        doSomeAction(project)
    }
}
```

However when I try to run it from my root (in order to run the task in every subproject) I get this error

```
Could not find method doSomeAction() for arguments [project ':projectA'] on task ':projectA:myTask'.
```

What is the problem? As far as I can see it seems it cannot find my method `doSomeAction(Project proj)`

Comment: works for me. what gradle version do you use? how do you run the task?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/34524213) you can find a demo with appropriately configured project, it works correctly. Do you have a `settings.gradle` file filled?

Comment: Indeed. It seems there is an issue in my gradle method that gives me such error as I removed whole code from the method and it worked.

Comment: Indeed. Apache library threw exception and it failed with this no message.